# How can I list features associated to an epic with a flat list query?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Sprint 146 in Azure DevOps introduced the possibility to embed queries in the Wiki. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-146-update#embed-azure-boards-query-results-in-wiki

I have a query that lists all the features added to an epic and extracts data like this:

- Epic X

  - Feature 1
  - Feature 2
  - Feature 3

This is "Work item and direct links" kind of query, but the Wiki accepts only "Flat list of work items" query. Is there a way to achieve the same result with this type of query?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
Work Item Type = Epic
AND ID = 1234
AND *GET ALL ASSOCIATED FEATURES*
```

The result will be a list of features, but will be good enough for my purpose. Features are epics' children.

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long-standing issue with the need for a "Flat list of work items", the Dashboard widgets that require a flat list also don't accept a Work Items + Direct Links, show (Parent | Child).

I suggest you file a suggestion over at [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).

A trick to bypass this problem is to use a tool, like the [TFS Aggregator CLI](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/aggregator-cli) (currently in beta testing), to automatically populate a field on each work item with their Parent ID. You can then filter on that using the standard flat-list.